# Creating new dart project in Intellij IDEA 13.1.5 community edition

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I wanted to play a little bit with the dart language and since recently I'm trying to switch from eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA I wanted to use that IDE. Unfortunately I can't figure out how I can create new dart project.

I've installed the dart plugin and installation looks fine - I have the plugin directory on my hard drive, dart's formatting options in settings etc. But I don't have any dart related option in the new project dialog (only java, maven, gradle, empty project etc.).

All resources I found told about using the new project dialog, or using WebStorm (like https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Getting+started+with+Dart ).

Is it possible at all? Am I missing something?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5 community edition.

EDIT: 
Ticket created: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14060

Comment: I use WebStorm and most of the time I just create a folder and a `pubspec.yaml` inside that folder and then open the folder using `File` > `open`. When I create and open a new `*.dart` file in a subfolder like `web` or `lib` the editor asks me if I want to enable Dart support for the project.
I also tried the `File` > `New project` assistant or enable Dart support manually in the settings. I don't know how different IntelliJ is but maybe it helps a bit to get you started.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I used Stagehand (recommended by user3216897), which generated pubspec.yaml and some *.dart files (see my comment to the mentioned answer). So I actually did what you suggested, but in a different way :) Nevertheless I'm still wondering if it's possible to create new dart project directly from IDEA...

Comment: Have you talked to JetBrains or filed a bug there? I'm not actually sure of IDEA CE has the Dart plugin.

Comment: @SethLadd it looks like it has dart plugin since I'm able to install it :). I found out that it works in the same build of ultimate edition and in community edition of IDEA14 preview. Also it looks like there was similar problem which was fixed in february. I created a ticket with more details: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that there is a bug in community edition of 13.1.x and it won't be fixed (but it's already fixed in community edition version 14 and it works in any version of ultimate edition) - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14060

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using Stagehand (http://stagehand.pub/). It's a great new command-line tool that creates well-formed Dart project folders, complete with pubspec.yaml and even build.dart for Polymer projects. The tool can create console apps, web apps, Polymer apps, and AngularDart apps.

Comment: Thanks. I used Stagehand to generate project, later imported it to IntelliJ, it noticed *.dart file and asked me about enabling dart support. Later using [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-and-debugging-dart.html) I was able to actually run this app. But that's rather a workaround (actual problem is creating dart project in IDEA), so I guess I shouldn't mark the answer as accepted (and unfortunately I'm not able to upvote the answer...).